# Динамический :src возвращаемый из геттера или функции, Vue, Vite, Vutify

Tags: html, vue.js, vue3

Мне нужно чтобы функция `getIcons()` каждый раз при вызове возвращала новый путь который подставится в `:src="getIcons()"` и отобразит иконку. Только мой подход почему-то не работает. Вместо 25 картинок я получаю 25 ошибок в консоли `404 (Not Found)`. Хотя путь я возвращаю верный.

```
<template>
    <div class="pt-8">
        <img
            v-for="icon in icons"
            :src="getIcons()"
            alt="Icon"
        >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const icons = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25']

        const getIcons = () => {
            const rndIcon = icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length)]
            return `../icons/viking-icons-48px/${rndIcon}.webp`;
        }

        return {
            getIcons,
            icons
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: А зачем ```..``` в начале пути? Для корневой страницы этот путь оказывается за пределами адресного пространства сайта.

Comment: Да вы правы. пути вида `../` ведут в никуда. Я указал прямой от папки `/src` и это заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак спустя тысячи перестановок src и чтения документации vite(у меня проект собран на vuetify в нём по умолчанию используется  vite).
Я пришёл к правильному решению этого вопроса. Всё, что нужно было сделать это просто указывать пути от `src`.
Вот простой вариант, который работает

```js
function testSrc(name) {
 return `/src/icons/viking-icons-48px/${name}.webp`
}
```

А вот более сложный с офф документации, но тоже рабочий. Какой более правильный не знаю. Оставлю оба.

```js
function getImageUrl(name) {
 return new URL(`/src/icons/viking-icons-48px/${name}.webp`, 
 import.meta.url).href
}
```

Варианты через `@/icons/viking-icons-48px/${name}.webp` не работают и отображают битые картинки.
Только полный путь от src привёл к успеху `/src/icons/viking-icons-48px/${name}.webp`